# How to create a new text format filter?

Tags: 8, input-formats

I am trying to create a new filter for iframe reponsiveness purposes on `admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html`, but I cannot see the filter. It is listed as enabled filters on `admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html`.

What am I missing?

I took `FilterAlign.php` as example, and this is the content of the `amu_dud_custom_filters/src/Plugin/Filter/AmuDudFilters.php` file I am using for the input format filter:

```
namespace Drupal\amu_dud_custom_filters\Plugin\Filter;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Html;
use Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult;
use Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterBase;

/**
 * Provides a filter to align elements.
 *
 * @Filter(
 *   id = "iframe",
 *   title = @Translation("iframe"),
 *   description = @Translation(("restrict iframe to 100% height for responsiveness")),
 *   type = Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterInterface::TYPE_TRANSFORM_REVERSIBLE
 * )
 */
class AmuDudFilters extends FilterBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process($text, $langcode) {
        $result = new FilterProcessResult($text);

        if (stristr($text, 'data-align') !== FALSE) {
            $dom = Html::load($text);
            $result->setProcessedText(Html::serialize($dom));
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

**Note**: uninstalling and reinstalling the module make the enabled filters visible in the list, but a discoveryTrait exception occured.

For making custom filters, is it neccessary to create a plugin manager class?

https://www.drupal.org/node/1637730

Comment: Have you enabled module and cleared cache?

Comment: apparently not when the code was right. So i have uninstalled and reinstalled and now it appears :) is there anything to worry about or implementing the process method is enough for it to work ?

Comment: how to solve PHP message: Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: "The "iframe" plugin does not exist." at /var/aegir/platforms/drupal8-dev/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php line 52" while reading response header from upstream, request: "GET /admin/config/content/formats/manage/basic_html HTTP/1.1"